# Lambda/LINQ Select Minimum

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I'm writing a function using the .NET `GeoCoordinate` class. We have an `Airport` class and a `City` class, both of which define their own `GeoCoordinate`.

I need to select the nearest airport relative to the city, and I am trying to do so using the `GetDistanceTo()` method.

What I have right now looks something like this:

```
Airport a = Airports.GetAllActiveAirports().Min(this.Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(n.Profile.Coordinates));
```

Another (working) function that retrieves a list of nearest airports by distance uses:

```
List<Airports> airports = Airports.GetAllActiveAirports();
var nearby = 
    from a in airports
    where this.Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(a.Profile.Coordinates) > d
    select a;
foreach(Airport a in nearby)
{ 
    airports.Remove(a); 
}
```

I've seen examples of doing things like this in a single line with LINQ & lambdas, but I'm not entirely sure how to execute this one...any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get your question, this line gets the minimum distance from Coordinates to an active airport.

```
Airports.GetAllActiveAirports().Min(_ => Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(_.Profile.Coordinates))
```

If you want the airport in question then:

```
var airports = Airports.GetAllActiveAirports();
var closest = airports.First(_ => Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(_.Profile.Coordinates) == airports.Min(_ => Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(_.Profile.Coordinates)))
```

You don't have to keep it in one line... Visual Studio won't run out of space.

An even better option, without getting the minimum in every iteration would be:

```
var airports = Airports.GetAllActiveAirports();
var minDistance = airports.Min(_ => Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(_.Profile.Coordinates))
var closest = airports.First(_ => Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(_.Profile.Coordinates) == minDistance)
```

Comment: Correct. It should return the object with the least/minimum distance... it is being executed on a `City` object though which I think is tripping me up.

Comment: funny that your question is about airports while your reputation is 747.

Comment: Indeed haha...didn't even notice it. So basically we're checking if the value returned from `GetDistanceTo` is equal to the Min, and returning the object if it is?

Comment: pretty much. You can do it in a single foreach clause. but if you're already using linq i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I've already done it with a foreach...this was more for the learning factor than anything

Comment: always important. sorry for ruining your rep to a boring 749

Comment: @mike You should definitely use the last option: calculate `minDistance` before `closest` query. This way makes at most `2*n` `GetDistanceTo()` calls, when the one with `Min` inside `First` can take up to `n*(n+1)` calls!

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer causes 2 calls to `GetDistance` for each airport. Here's how you can do it in a single pass:

```
var closestAirport = Airports.GetAllActiveAirports()
    .Select(x => new {
        Airport = x, 
        Distance = this.Coordinates.GetDistanceTo(x.Profile.Coordinates)})
    .Aggregate((a1, a2) => a1.Distance < a2.Distance ? a1 : a2)
    .Airport;
```

Answer (score 1):

Min will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if there are no values.  You might try something like this.  If none are found, closest will be null:

```
var closest = Airports.GetAllActiveAirports().OrderBy(x => x.GetDistanceTo(n.Profile.Coordinates)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault isn't in the right place. It will run on a single airport.

Comment: It won't even compile, unless `Airport` implements `IEnumerable<Something>`.

Comment: plus, orderBy is heavier and unnecessary because it will order **all** items and not just the first